# Put column data into the correct destination column sql ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am having some issues with order data from a system - different column type error.

I am using SSIS to extract the data into a table

However I am faced with some records looking like this

```
CUSTOMERID DATE       ITEMID     ITEM 
1          10/04/2017 A1456      TABLE 
2          20/05/2017 A3432      CHAIR 
3          16/06/2017 A3432      CHAIR 
4          18/06/2017 Null       A3432,CHAIR 
5          23/06/2017 A1456      TABLE
```

Is there some SQL code, or a process I can use in SSIS that can help correct the issue with ID 4 to put the ITEMID into the correct row and separating the item as follows?

```
CUSTOMERID DATE       ITEMID     ITEM 
1          10/04/2017 A1456      TABLE 
2          20/05/2017 A3432      CHAIR 
3          16/06/2017 A3432      CHAIR 
4          18/06/2017 A3432      CHAIR 
5          23/06/2017 A1456      TABLE
```

Comment: You need to locate first `,` sign and take everything before it and put it in the first column with sql function like `substring` and do the same with the second part. Depending on your DBMS system (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server) there may be a different function to do so.

Comment: Please provide more detail about data source, is it from a CSV file, excel file, or other Database system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add 2 derived column with the following expression:

**ITEMID**

```
ISNULL([ITEMID]) ? TOKEN([ITEM],",",1) : [ITEMID]
```

**ITEM**

```
TOKENCOUNT([ITEM],",") > 1 ? TOKEN([ITEM],",",TOKENCOUNT([ITEM],",")) : [ITEM]
```

**References**

- [TOKEN (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/token-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)
- [TOKENCOUNT (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/tokencount-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)